# installing windows only R packages in Ubuntu

Tags: r

I have a R package that i need to use. The package in question is [BQuant](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~ovitek/BQuant-Web/index.htm).

The package is downloadable as a [zip file](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~ovitek/BQuant-Web/BQuant/BQuant_1.0.zip) which (I found out later) contains windows binaries. First I tried to extract these binaries and pack it in .tar.gz And i installed the .tar.gz package using install.packages().

This didn't give any error but when i tried to call any function of the package R gave me the error: `Error: could not find function <function_name>`.

So then i found the [source files](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~ovitek/BQuant-Web/BQuant/BQuant_1.0_Source.zip) and tried extracting and repacking in .tar.gz. This time, during the installation the error was: `**ERROR:  Windows-only package**`

When i checked the description in the [source files](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~ovitek/BQuant-Web/BQuant/BQuant_1.0_Source.zip) it said `OS_type: windows`. I removed that line and tried again. This time the error was:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -o BQuant.so dp.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
dp.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make:  ***[BQuant.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘BQuant’
```

So in brief:
 **I need to know whether this windows package can be installed in Linux.**

Comment: That does not liik like source files, as it contains two binary files (the .dll and the .o). You could try to remove these, but that will likely not work.

Comment: Source files are there in the folder named "R"

Comment: I'd send an email to the package author and ask for a Linux binary, or alternatively, for the package sources. Under linux it should be quite straightforward to build the package from source.

Comment: In addition, the package is already quite old (2008) and does not seem to be maintained.

Comment: The **source** is not only in the R dir. You need the sources for the compiled code. That zip **is** a windows binary as the R sources and C/Fortran sources have been compiled into code from their original versions - even the R code has been "compiled" (i.e. made into a format that is not the raw source code).

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Yes the package seems to be quite old. But i really do need it. I had already sent a mail to the author. I am waiting for a reply.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yes i see what you mean now. So if i had the raw source code it might work? AND if i cant get my hands on the raw source is there anything else i can do?

Comment: If you have the source and meet all dependencies (R packages mainly) you should be fine. Use the source Luke! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change a bit in the 'BQuant\R\fcn_preproc.r' file.

This file loads the dll file, which is a windows only file.

```
.First.lib <- function(lib, pkg) 
{
   library.dynam("BQuant.dll")
}
```

You might try to add a test based on platform.

```
.First.lib <- function(lib, pkg) 
{
   if(.Platform$OS.type == 'windows'){
      library.dynam("BQuant.dll")
   }
   if(.Platform$OS.type == 'unix'){
      library.dynam("BQuant.so")
   }
}
```

This might do the trick.
Also don't forget to change the os line the dependent file.

To try to compile the .c file, you can use this command from terminal.

```
R CMD SHLIB -o BQuant.so dc.c
```

As per : http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/interface.pdf and http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~prangle/CinR/CinR.pdf

Comment: If this does not work try deleting the dc.o file and run g++ -c dc.c. This will make a new dc.o file which can probably compiled by R

Comment: Any idea where i can find the R.h header file?

Comment: in the folder ~/R/include. At least for windows installations.

Comment: Have you checked?  From memory: the R directory is located in \usr\R or \usr\local\R and the include folder should be within the R folder.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see there is no compiled code object for unix/linux. The zip you link to really is just a windows binary and is missing the sources that you would need to compile into the equivalent of BQuant.dll on linux. Even the R code is in "compiled" form, i.e. not plain text R code.

Unless you have the source code then you won't be able to compile this to work on Linux. Ontact the maintainer to see if they can provide a proper source package.

Comment: plain text R code is there in the "R" folder in this archive: http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~ovitek/BQuant-Web/BQuant/BQuant_1.0_Source.zip

Comment: okay..i see what you mean to say now. is there anything i could do without the source code?

Comment: I doubt it depends on how much of the package leverages the compiled functions in `BQuant.dll`. If it is restricted to one function you dn't need then you could probably do a lot by stripping out the R codes and sourcing all but those loading and using the dll. If the functions you need use the dll then you are out of luck without the sources to compile it.

Comment: there is also a .C file in the src folder. Could you have a look at it for me? Mischa Vreeburg in his(her?) answer suggested compiling the C code to get the .o file which can then be specified in place of the .dll

Comment: @guy The package is too big for me to start doing a code review to see what is and is not required - also, I don't know if `dp.c` is a replacement for `BQuant.dll`. The package `DESCRIPTION` states the package is released under the GPL-v2, so ask the authors for the full set of sources as they are obliged to provide and ask them what the dll is for?